# How to run JBPM 7.48 on Websphere 9.5

Tags: java, webserver, websphere, jbpm

Anyone have experienced configure jbpm 7.48 on Websphere 9.5? Can help share the step with me?

I found some references but that one is an old version of jbpm, different from the latest one.

Also, I don't know how to create the war file for jbpm.

Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to kie-server, you could generate it by yourself from

https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/master/kie-server-parent/kie-server-wars/

with: `mvn clean install -DskipTests` (notice that you should build the whole repository from the parent)

It will create `kie-server-7.54.0-SNAPSHOT-ee7.war` (for the current master branch) that it's the right one for Websphere.